# Как отформатировать дату в GWT

Tags: gwt, java

Хочу отформатировать дату в gwt-приложении, но класс java.util.Calendar не получается использовать, недоступен. Что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Стоит добавить, что в gwt недоступны иногда отдельные методы. В частности, что касается форматирования, метод String.format(...) - недоступен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форматирование в GWT осуществляется с помощью классов пакета [com.google.gwt.i18n.client](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/package-summary.html). Примеры использования есть [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-examples/wiki/gwtDateTime#How_to_use_Date).

Answer (score 1):

Вот полезная [ссылка](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) по данному вопросу.

Не смотря на то, что это javadoc, примеров достаточно и они довольно подробные.